# How to make special shape with css

Tags: html, css

Is there any way to make this shape with CSS?

[image]

Comment: if you really need to use css for this, this documentation might help https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/SVG/Tutorial/SVG_and_CSS

Comment: However, you can turn this image into svg, which will be an html element that you can insert in your html and minuplate using css, to change color, size ...

Comment: Play with positions.